# PHP: Redirect same page after click the submit button

Tags: php, redirect, refresh, reload

Is there a way to redirects to the same page using PHP.??? I just need to reload or refresh the gridview. I don't need to redirect to a website or link, I need is redirect it to the same page or same form like main.php.

I already used the header(), but its not working to me and all I see is linking in the website.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is your code? Do you get an error message? If no do you have error reporting enabled? What does "its not working to me" mean exactly?

Comment: @PeeHaa埽...I just add this code in my main.php "<?php
header("location: checkbox_process.php");
?>" then I click the button its said that "The page isn't redirecting properly"

Comment: @PeeHaa埽...and also when I try to put it in some page its just leave a blank page

Comment: If you get an blank page you probably haven't enabled error reporting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Comment: @PeeHaa埽..Already tried but still blank page...

Comment: Also note that when redirecting using [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) you should always use the full URL.

Comment: Full URL is not necessary. The blank page is caused by another problem. Maybe add your full PHP code or check your php or webserver errorlog again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two example to redirect to a form.
Lets say that your filename is main.php

```
<form action="main.php">
Name: <input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Or you can use this

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
Name: <input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Did that answer your question?

Comment: This does not redirect. And will produce the annoying "submit data" message when refreshing the page.

Comment: @PeeHaa埽...It works..OMG..I didn't think about that... goodness..Thanks!.

Comment: @PeeHaa埽..hey are u still der?? I have another question

Comment: @PeeHaa is right, this is not a redirect to the origin site. This might be the right solution: ```header("Location: http://www.example.com/");```

Answer (score 10):

Simply do:

```
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
header("Location: $referer");
```

Answer (score 4):

You should redirect with a location header after every post, because otherwise when the user presses the refresh button, it will send again the same form...

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    file_put_contents('data.txt', $_POST['data']);
    header('location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
} else {
    header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"
          enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8">
        <input name="data" type="text" value="<?php echo file_get_contents('data.txt'); ?>"/>
        <button>küldés</button>
    </form>
<?php
}
```

Btw. if you want to do proper work, you should try out a php framework instead of this kind of spaghetti code...

Comment: I know this is old, but your 'spaghetti code' comment made me think you may be the right person to ask. I've been learning to code for a few years now in my spare time. Recently, I've gotten to a point where I feel I can start looking for employment and I'm building a portfolio. I have used a couple of frameworks in different projects and I'm wondering, other than showing off my ability to use it, is there any framework you'd say is worth using when the statement in your answer is the only php that I'll be using on the site?

Comment: @JoshuaFlood I work mostly with (node)js nowadays I don't even have the IDE for PHP projects. If you wanted to ask which PHP frameworks are really good, then Symfony and Laravel are. But if I were you I would just check whether the actual framework has many stars on its github page and if so, then it is popular, so it is worth to mention. I think it is a plus point if you use git, composer, phpunit and some sort of TDD or BDD approach to develop.

Comment: @JoshuaFlood I see you use Slim. I liked that too. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Unit testing is something I'm still having to spend a lot of time on google to work with, so I guess once that is a bit clearer in my head then I'll know how to answer my own question a bit better. Yeah I was just looking for something to help me develop a simple API that just returns JSON and all of the obvious choices seemed far too heavy, but Slim is definitely the most elegant framework I've found and I love that it doesn't really force devs into using any particular set of dependencies.